# Executing an if statement or try/catch based on whether or not the input is a string/int

Tags: c#, class, if-statement, try-catch

I am trying to create an if statement or try/catch that will hopefully execute under the condition that the input received in the console application (that I am converting to Int32) is NOT an integer. This is the code snippet I have been using:

```
            Console.WriteLine("What year was your car made? [MUST BE IN YEAR FORMAT]");
            caryearchk = Console.ReadLine();

            if (caryearchk.GetType() != int) // Can't figure out a way to return a bool through .GetType()
            {
                Console.Write("Error. you MUST submit this in an integer form. The application will now close.");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else
            {              
            }
            caryear = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("What is the drivetrain? [ FWD /// RWD /// AWD /// 4WD ]");
            cartrain = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        Car car = new Car(carmake,
```

If there are any other/more efficient ways to go about this I would much rather prefer that. I am eager to know many different ways to solve basic problems like this

Comment: If the Console.ReadLine(); returns a string like "two thousand and fifteen" wouldn't that result in the application closing with .TryParse() ? The goal for me is to be able to throw an error if the user inputs some sort of wrong format or unintentionally adds in a letter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

imho you are looking for:

```
int.TryParse(string, out int);
```

[TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) on msdn.

Comment: If the Console.ReadLine(); returns a string like "two thousand and fifteen" wouldn't that result in the application closing with .TryParse() ? The goal for me is to be able to throw an error if the user inputs some sort of wrong format

Comment: are you looking for: https://azure.microsoft.com/fr-fr/services/cognitive-services/language-understanding-intelligent-service/ ?

Comment: @S.Nog `int.TryParse` returns `false` if the parsing failed because the string wasn't in the right format.  It won't terminate the application on its own.

Answer (score 1):

`Console.ReadLine` returns a string. It's always going to be a string. You need to attempt to convert the value to an `int` with `int.TryParse`.

Answer (score 0):

```
       Console.WriteLine("What year was your car made? [MUST BE IN YEAR FORMAT]");
        caryearchk = Console.ReadLine();
        int caryearchkint;
        if (int.TryParse(caryearchk,caryearchkint) // Can't figure out a way to return a bool through .GetType()
        {
            Console.Write("Error. you MUST submit this in an integer form. The application will now close.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        else
        {              
        }
        caryear = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("What is the drivetrain? [ FWD /// RWD /// AWD /// 4WD ]");
        cartrain = Console.ReadLine();
    }
    Car car = new Car(carmake,
```

I believe int.TryParse is what you need.